Make Terraform update parent resource before deleting child resource
I am implementing a Terraform provider using the Terraform Plugin Framewok.
I have this resource main_resource, that can be linked to another resource sub_resource. On API side, a sub_resource can only be deleted if it as been unlinked from any resources.
Let's say we have the current tfstate :
resource "main_resource" "dummy" {
  sub_resource_id = sub_resource.dummy.id 
}

resource "sub_resource" "dummy" {}

And then we try to apply this plan :
resource "main_resource" "dummy" {}

Here is what I would like Terraform to do :

Update of main_resource.dummy (where sub_resource.dummy gets unlinked)
Delete of sub_resource.dummy

And here is what Terraform does :

Delete of sub_resource.dummy (Fails because the sub_resource is still linked to another resource)
Update of main_resource.dummy (We never reach this)

How can I make Terraform run this sequence in the wanted order on provider side ?
Note : When giving an empty plan instead of the one above, the resource are deleted in the wanted order (main_resource first, and sub_resource second)

Dependencies in Terraform are controlled entirely by the relationships described in the configuration. A provider cannot affect the dependency order. In this case the updated configuration includes no reference between main_resource.dummy and sub_resource.dummy and so Terraform believes it can perform those two operations independently, in any order or even concurrently. Unfortunately I don't think there's any way to make this work reliably all in one plan/apply round with today's Terraform, because there's no way to declare a dependency on something that has already been removed.
